# C++ FindProcessWindow in dll

Tags: c++, class, enums, window

Simple thing, find top-level window by class name that belongs to parent process of dll. From what I found on the internet I should

1. `EnumWindows` enumerate all top-level windows
2. in `EnumWindowsProc` compare class name `GetClassName` of enumerated window with desided name
3. If it is equal check `GetWindowThreadProcessId` is same as dlls parent pid

But I came across an obstacle, how to obtain PID of dll loader? Or maybe there is another way to find parent window by class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just use [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

You could also use the [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions, but that's probably overkill...